# Custom user profile titles interfering with user views block

Tags: views, theming, entities, users

I'm using this function to replace the titles on user pages with a user text field:

```
function MYMODULE_user_view($account, $view_mode, $langcode) {
  $wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('user', $account);
  $auth_name = $wrapper->field_account_auth_name->value();
  if ($auth_name) {
    drupal_set_title('Profile overview for ' . $auth_name;
  } else {
    drupal_set_title('Profile overview for ' . $account->name);
  }
}
```

It works as it should, but when I add a view block with user entities it makes every page have the same title. It's `Profile overview for ' . $auth_name;` for the first user with a non-empty field_account_auth_name. If I delete that user the next user takes its place. This is for all pages too, not just ones with the block in it.

If it matters I'm using this function

```
  function MYMODULE_preprocess_user_profile(&$vars) {
    if ($vars['elements']['#view_mode'] == 'auth') {
      $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'user_profile__auth';
    }
  }
```

with a user entity "auth" I created using [Entity View Mode](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_view_mode), with this in user-profile--auth.tpl:

```
<div class="authProfile"<?php print $attributes; ?>>
  <?php print render($user_profile); ?>  
</div>
```

and setting auth as the view mode in the view block. But the title problem happens with the user account view mode as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could check the url using the arg function and only set the title if the current page is a user/* page. You could try something like the following.

```
function MYMODULE_user_view($account, $view_mode, $langcode) {
  if (arg(0) == 'user') {
    $wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('user', $account);
    $auth_name = $wrapper->field_account_auth_name->value();
    if ($auth_name) {
      drupal_set_title('Profile overview for ' . $auth_name;
    } else {
      drupal_set_title('Profile overview for ' . $account->name);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you using arg(0) as a placeholder? I don't know php very well. I know of current_path() but AFAIK it only allows for specific URLs, not path/1, path/2, etc.

Comment: Nevermind I messed up. It's no longer on all pages, but it's still just using the first user with a non-empty field_account_auth_name on all user pages. I tried `if (empty($auth_name))  . . . $account->name) else . . . $auth_name` but it's the same. Any ideas?

Comment: arg is a Drupal function that returns the ith part of the current path. So arg(0) returns the first part of the path (everything after the domain and before the first slash). See https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/arg/7

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is. Are you having problems on pages with multiple users? I imagine that on those pages it would be the last user's name that gets rendered.

Comment: Okay gotcha. No it's on single user pages, just the regular ?q=user/*. If the view block is in a region then every user page's title is "Profile overview for x's field_account_auth_name", x being the oldest user if I set the sort criteria to User: Created date (desc), and newest if I set it to asc. I'm pretty confused.

Comment: Could it be the way I'm using views pages/blocks in combination? To be more semantic and consistent with template files/paths I make views pages then use page--path.tpl, instead of an article / custom path / page--node--x.tpl. Within that page--path.tpl I call the regions, and in the regions are views blocks. Seems unlikely it's that but I don't know.

Comment: If you call drupal_set_title multiple times, the actual title will be the string passed the last time it was called. So this makes sense that the title would be the oldest user. In this case you probably don't want to call drupal_set_title at all if you're on a user page so you should change my code sample to have the following line instead. if (arg(0) != 'user') {

Comment: With (arg(0) != 'user') no title change is made though. It's just "username | site name". I want the title of ?q=user/* to be "Profile overview for username | sitename" if the field is empty and "Profile overview for field | sitename" if it isn't. It works as it should without the view. If views templates weren't so limiting I would just use user fields, but I have to render custom profiles to theme it properly. Frustrating!

Comment: Hmm, maybe it would be easier to just change the title by creating a page-user.tpl.php file, where you replace the standard title with your custom php code. Not a great solution but i know it would work. Or you could use drupal_static to count how many times your function has been called and only call drupal_set_title the first time (which will be the real user).

Comment: I went back and really looked at the views templates, and I was able to get it how I needed it with fields. All of the if statements just threw me off the first time. Still some unnecessary divitis going on but I don't mind.